# HTTPS overhead compared to HTTP

Tags: performance, https

HTTPS is the encrypted version of HTTP, and nowadays it is becoming a common practice to encrypt all the web traffic, not only sensitive one.

The drawback of HTTPS, apart from the need to buy expensive certificates and being dependent of a third party Certification Authority, is the increased CPU load (for the actual encryption) and bandwidth consumption (for addition protocol negotiation).

This overhead is not only a server side problem, but also a higher latency perceived by the client.

What is the actual overhead in terms of CPU load, bandwidth and latency?

What's the state of the art (on software, hardware and best practices) to reduce this overhead?

Comment: Sidenote: you can get free class 1 certificates at Startcom. As for the encryption, there is hardware support for AES used for disk encryption. You could look into the possible of hardware support for OpenSSL HTTPS.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

<sub>**2024 update below**</sub>

---

- **Price** : There's heaps of CA's and resellers that provide well supported SSL certificates that are even affordable for your Mom's recipe website, let alone for business use. Besides a couple of free ones, as in beer, others are still cheaper then a pint. So no issue there.
- **Latency is increased by switching to HTTPS** : the initial SSL handshake requires two extra roundtrips before the connection is established, compared to just the one roundtrip required to establish a TCP connection to the plain unencrypted HTTP port. So effectively it will take three times as long before the first data is received by your users.

[image: From: High Performance Browser Networking by Ilya Grigorik]

- **Bandwidth Increase** : The used bandwidth will increase slightly as the header size will increase by a number of bytes for protocol reasons and the effective payload will decrease a due to the framing overhead, and some ciphers will use padding as well. Assume a common MTU of 1500 bytes packet size ; the HTTPS protocol overhead will still leave at least 1400 bytes effective payload data size, therefore in max 6-7% increase in bandwidth.
- **CPU Load** : The most computational expensive part is the public key exchange, after which a relatively efficient symmetric cypher is used. Most quotes suggest that modern commodity hardware does not require SSL offload cards to deal with that overhead.

> In January this year (2010), Gmail switched to using HTTPS for
> everything by default. Previously it had been introduced as an option,
> but now all of our users use HTTPS to secure their email between their
> browsers and Google, all the time. In order to do this we had to
> deploy no additional machines and no special hardware. On our
> production frontend machines, SSL/TLS accounts for less than 1% of the
> CPU load, less than 10 KB of memory per connection and less than 2% of
> network overhead. Many people believe that SSL/TLS takes a lot of CPU
> time and we hope the preceding numbers (public for the first time)
> will help to dispel that.
>
> If you stop reading now you only need to remember one thing: SSL/TLS
> is not computationally expensive any more.
> -- *Adam Langley (Google)*

A good resource is chapter 4 from [High Performance Browser Networking](https://hpbn.co/transport-layer-security-tls/) by Ilya Grigorik

In conclusion, the overhead except for the latency in establishing a new connection, is negligible.

What is best, it depends on your needs... Using a CDN might become more expensive when you also need SSL support for instance.

## 2024 - 10 Years later

#### HTTPS is everywhere and the internet is faster than ever.

**Price:** In 2016 [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) became publicly available and significantly changed the lanscape. Their ACME client certbot (and other implementations) made getting valid and widely accepted certificates completely free of charge and deploying them  trivial.

**Latency:** More or less in parallel protocol improvements led to [TLS 1.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_1.3) that removed the extra steps from the handshake:

[image: https://www.a10networks.com/glossary/key-differences-between-tls-1-2-and-tls-1-3/]

**CPU load:** And of course all CPU's , not only server CPU's, but also the more lightweight CPU's in appliances, in smart phones, etc. etc. all now have built in support for offloading cryptographic calculations to the silicon.

As a result there are hardly any relevant websites left are not (also) available on HTTPS and most plain HTTP sites only exist to redirect to HTTPS.

Browser can be configured to [use HTTPS by default](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/set-https-default-your-browser) to avoid the latency of first going to the plain HTTP only to be redirect to HTTPS. And there are things like [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) and even complete TLD's that won't allow plain HTTP anymore for any site because they're on the [HSTS preload list](https://hstspreload.org/) and where even when you manually enter `HTTP://some.example.dev` the browser will immediately go to `HTTPS://some.example.dev`. See for example: [List of top-level domains (TLDs) that require HTTPS connections, like .dev](https://serverfault.com/q/1067229/37681)

Rather than showing that a site is "secure" and uses HTTPS and an valid certificate, or the "green bar" when the site uses an extended validation certificate, ***browser have started to alert users when a site is ***insecure*** and not available on HTTPS instead***.

Comment: **Free** SSL certs that can give you a green bar? How is that possible?

Comment: @pacerier I said well supported i.e. accepted without warning messages by the vast majority of current browsers. Those are cheap. Cheap enough not to use self signed certificateso.   EV certificates that give the green bar are a marketing tool and not significantly different from normal certificates from a technical perspective.

Comment: @HBruijin, What would be some examples? certs are useless if they aren't accepted. From a Chrome's perspective, "a user go to a https page and see a green bar" compared to "a user go to a https page and see a [Warning page](https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=100x100&chl=otpauth%3A%2F%2Ftotp%2FTest123%204%3Fsecret%3DTKQWCOOJ7KJ4ZIR) with no obvious way to proceed" is a **huge** difference.

Comment: And there is of course the intermediate, no green bar but no security warnings either...

Comment: Yes, there are free cert options. The best known is **[LetsEncrypt.org](https://letsencrypt.org/)**

Comment: @HBruijn I'm sad that I can't re-upvote and re-accept your answer 10 years later! Kudos for updating this with current information!

Comment: Thank you for your kind words. Since the Q&A  was upvoted yesterday by somebody else, it apparently still features in peoples search results and deserved an update.