# AWS Redis Encryption in-transit + TLS EC2 Connection

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, redis

I'm already using AWS Elasticache Redis but without "Encryption in-transit". I've created a new small/temp cluster with this Encryption Enabled but I can't connect to it -

```
redis-cli error: Connection reset by peer

eg: redis-cli -h aws.host.name -p 6379
```

Note: connects fine when In-Transit Encryption isn't enabled on a Redis Cluster.

I'm sure this is because I'm not using TLS Encryption from the EC2 instance:

"To connect to an in-transit encryption enabled cluster, a database must be enabled for transport layer security (TLS). To connect to a cluster that is not in-transit encryption enabled, the database cannot be TLS-enabled."

Questions:

- I'm really not sure how to enable TLS encryption on EC2. How to I do this? Do I need to use an stunnel or can I use AWS SSL Certs?
- What impact on performance would/could this have?
- I'm also looking at Redis AUTH Password. Is this a big performance hit? I'm guessing if Redis is frequency hit it could well do.

thanks so much.

Comment: I observed the same issue: 'Connection reset by peer' errors when trying to reach Redis elasticache from a Lambda function within a VPC. I assume my security group and subnet settings were correct, because when I disabled encryption, it worked.

Comment: [redis-cli doesn't support SSL #221](https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis/issues/221)

Answer (score 4):

The standard client, redis-cli doesn't support encryption.  There is a list of redis clients which support ssl/TLS encryption at https://redislabs.com/blog/secure-redis-ssl-added-to-redsmin-and-clients/

Answer (score 1):

- You don't need to use stunnel. The standard `redis-cli -h aws.host.name -p 6379` should work from your EC2 instance. Check that you can connect to the host and port (simply `telnet host 6379`). If there is no connection, then check the security group settings of your ElastiCache cluster (you need to have inbound port 6379 rule, its configured in EC2 tab, Security Groups section).
- There is some network overhead (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615882/how-much-network-overhead-does-tls-add-compared-to-a-non-encrypted-connection) and additional CPU (see [HTTPS overhead compared to HTTP](https://serverfault.com/questions/570387/https-overhead-compared-to-http)). I don't expect this to be significant for most applications. All depends on how you using it, so run your own tests.
- Redis AUTH exchange only happens when you establish the session. Should be no additional overhead thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

The standard redis client (aka the redis-cli which comes with the redis server) does not support TLS.

That's why when in-transit encryption is disabled is connects successfully to the server. You should use a client that supports TLS.