# apache2: /etc/hosts won't redirect to apache2

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost, apache2

I have newly installed apache2 and by visiting `localhost` apache2 is shown to be up and running. I want the same to happen when I put `app` in the browser. When I do try to go visit `app` the browser gives a `Unable to connect` message.

**What I have done so far**

I changed my `etc/hosts/` file to include `app`.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost app
127.0.1.1   ubuntu
...
```

I would then expect `http://app/` to resolve to the apache2 page(as I want it to), but that doesn't happen. Therefore I tried to ping `app`. This worked and was shown to resolve to `127.0.0.1`.

Next I tried to restart `apache2`, but the result stayed the same.

Why do I get `Unable to connect` message and how do I make it redirect me to apache2?

**EDIT:**

I've tried to add `app` here too.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app
    ServerAlias www.app
    ServerAdmin webmaster@app
    DocumentRoot /var/www/app

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/app-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/app-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I then run the command `a2ensite app.conf` and then I restart apache2 with `systemctl reload apache2`.

Still when I put `app` in the browser field I get a `Unable to connect` message.

Comment: Hmm. Don't use a browser, but something that will actually give you a useful error message e.g. curl.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Why does curl work, but not the browser?

Comment: Did you actually use the literal string `app`? You can't do that. It is a real live domain on the Internet and you don't own it. Use something else, like a subdomain of your own domain name.

Comment: I used actually used `app.dev`.

Comment: That's also a real live domain, you don't own it, and every domain in `dev` must use HTTPS. Browsers strictly enforce this.

Comment: Thank you again! That fixed my problem entirely. Is it a standard of some sorts that `dev` and probably others like `com` enforce https?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/1067229/126632